# How to input foreign unicode characters into XeLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode

Friends,

I am working on a XeLaTeX document. I am almost done with my document, but I need to input text from a foreign language. I am running Mac OS X. I go to Preferences > Language & Text and in there I enable Gurmukhi - QWERTY. This allows me to input Punjabi characters, which I am able to see in MS Word. I want to input the following unicode characters:

```
ਰੋਂਦਾ ਬੱਚਾ  ਿੲਕ
```

However, when I simply paste it into my TeXworks file, it simply does not show up when I compile a PDF file. I have indeed tried to google this, but came up with nothing other than adding some of these statements to my preamble. I am pretty desperate at this point.

My preamble already looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} %options: [a4paper, leqno, 11pt]
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[cm-default]{fontspec}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% -----Page Style-------------
\pagestyle{plain}

% -----Symbols----------------

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to load a font which contains these characters. Load an appropriate font using `\setmainfont` and all should be well.

Comment: someone by jleedev was able to solve my problem, suggesting I do this: 

    \newfontfamily\gu{Gurmukhi MT}
    \begin{document}
    {\gu ਰੋਂਦਾ ਬੱਚਾ  ਿੲਕ}
It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

If you don’t want to (or can’t) use the same font for both alphabets, I think you have to explicitly choose the font when you need it.

```
\newfontfamily\gu{Gurmukhi MT}
\begin{document}
{\gu ਰੋਂਦਾ ਬੱਚਾ  ਿੲਕ}
```

(On Mac you can use “Gurmukhi MT”; FreeSans and FreeSerif also contain the glyphs.)

Also: The `inputenc` package warns that it should not be loaded as XeTeX already uses UTF8.